# EE 1.6.7 entries order within a category

Tags: categories, orderby

I'm using this code:

```
{exp:weblog:categories weblog="games" style="none" show_empty="no"}
{exp:weblog:entries site="games_site" weblog="games" category="{category_id}" style="linear" disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" } 
{title}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
{/exp:weblog:categories}
```

to display all the entries for all categories assigned to a specific weblog.
This works ok, but I would like to maintain the order given to the entry inside each category.
Is there a specific orderby parameter to use?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like these entries and categories to be ordered, and possibly how the order looks now?

Comment: When you assign an entry to one or more categories (using the category tab), you can see on the right column a section called "Order Entries" which show the order of that specific entry in all the selected categories. Inside that section you can move up and down the entry changing the order inside a specific category. I'd like to be able to sort entries using exactly that order

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "Order Entries" function in the Category tab. Can you send a screen shot of this? Is this function created by a third party add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigations I understand that the items order is managed by a 3rd party plugin. Unfortunately I can't tell which plugin it is but apparently it adds an "order by" custom field type which contains the information about the order within the category.
I wasn't aware of this particular plugin since I didn't create the EE site in the first place.
Thanks anyway for the support.